# Adjusting region not working on iOS for maps

Tags: ios, xcode, maps

So I have added a UIMap to my view controller and linked it to "mapView" reference. The coordinates work perfectly on the map too. However, I cannot zoom my map into the coordinates! What am I doing wrong?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D _coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon); //lat and lon are previously declared location values
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(_coords, 250, 250)];
[self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES]; //I have tried this with and without the self
 self.mapView.delegate = self;  
MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = _coords;
annotationPoint.title = @"George's House";
[mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
 [mapView selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:YES];
```

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing? What do you expect to see? Can you confirm that the adjustedRegion and self.mapView are what you expect? (Try looking at them in the debugger or logging them.)

Comment: Just the map at full screen. My problem is that it is not adjusting. Sorry.

Comment: Can you add more details? For example, the values of _coords, adjustedRegion and self.mapView? What function is the code you posted in?

Comment: The value of coords is lat, lon, which would be generated by a server. They could be anything, but they are float values. I know that works because it does plot the points. The adjust region should fit the "_coords" with the determined zoom level. However, it doesn't. Being honest, I don't think self.mapView is necessary, but as I said in my comments, I found it did not matter when I changed that. Thanks for helping though. Any thoughts?

Comment: try to move the line with mapView.delegate more up

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you look at the value of adjustedRegion and see if it's all zeros? Try making the `mapView` on the second line `self.mapView`.